# filter column in data frame by two conditions in another column

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

Lets say we have something like this

```
df <- data.frame(species = c("Passer", "Turdus", "Turdus", "Gallus", "Anas", "Anas"),
                 season = c("breeding", "breeding", "non-breeding", "non-breeding", "breeding", "non-breeding"), 
                 value = seq(1, 12, 2), 
                 drop = c("no", "no", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat"))
```

```
  species       season value drop
1  Passer     breeding     1   no
2  Turdus     breeding     3   no
3  Turdus non-breeding     5  dog
4  Gallus non-breeding     7  dog
5    Anas     breeding     9  cat
6    Anas non-breeding    11  cat
```

I would like to select the rows that have species with both values of breeding season, i.e. breeding and non-breeding.

The outcome should look like this

```
  species       season value drop
2  Turdus     breeding     3   no
3  Turdus non-breeding     5  dog
5    Anas     breeding     9  cat
6    Anas non-breeding    11  cat
```

I gave it a couple tries with filter() but I couldn’t make it work. I suspect making a loop could be the way to go?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If there are just the possibility of species appears two times, you can use this:

```
library(dplyr)

 df %>% 
   add_count(species) %>% 
   filter(n == 2) %>% 
   select(-n)

  species       season value drop
1  Turdus     breeding     3   no
2  Turdus non-breeding     5  dog
3    Anas     breeding     9  cat
4    Anas non-breeding    11  cat
```

Another way would be to do this

```
df %>% 
  group_by(species) %>% 
  filter(nlevels(factor(season)) == 2)
```

Comment: The second alternative did the trick. Many thanks!